# Detect when wearable changed into theater/cinema mode

Tags: android, wear-os

Has anyone come across a way to detect the change into this mode. I can't find any events for it but it would be handy to know for my app.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Android framework doesn't publicly expose this information. However, if you would like to respect this setting and not disturb the user when the theater mode is on (I assume that's why you are asking), you can try experimenting with an unofficial way.

`THEATER_MODE_ON` is defined in [`Settings.Global`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Global.html), but it's hidden. However, you should be able to still access it with [`Settings.Global.getInt(ContentResolver, String)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Global.html#getInt(android.content.ContentResolver,%20java.lang.String)) if you just use the string `theater_mode_on`. Check the constant on grepcode: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.0_r1/android/provider/Settings.java#5104

You can also try to set a content observer, since you know the constant value. However, keep in mind this is an unofficial, `@hide` API so your app might get broken in the future releases.

Comment: Thanks for that. Seems a little crazy to not expose this but even though hidden given its just using getInt and not reflection to a hidden method  I guess it shouldn't be too bad to use.

Comment: This is not working on my Galaxy Watch 4 with Wear OS 3, it is always returning 0, so my app is not respecting it. The value is definitely in the `Settings.Global`, because it is not returning the default value, but it always returns 0. It is working fine in Wear OS 3 emulator. Is there any workaround for the Galaxy Watch?